# How to open GPS settings an android device?

Tags: java, android, actionscript-3

I am making GPS android app (with air for android) and what I want is if GPS is off I want to open GPS settings on device or switch GPS on but I don't know how. I want to do it in AS3 or open android settings in Java. Thanks for help!

Answer (score 57, accepted):

You can simply start an activity with this action:

```
startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS));
```

I use it inside a dialog:

```
public static void displayPromptForEnablingGPS(final Activity activity)
    {

        final AlertDialog.Builder builder =  new AlertDialog.Builder(activity);
        final String action = Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS;
        final String message = "Do you want open GPS setting?";

        builder.setMessage(message)
            .setPositiveButton("OK",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface d, int id) {
                        activity.startActivity(new Intent(action));
                        d.dismiss();
                    }
            })
            .setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface d, int id) {
                        d.cancel();
                    }
            });
        builder.create().show();
    }
```

Comment: but when I go to this activity `Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS` and enable gps and again come back to my application then my gps doesnt seems to be enabled for the application and when i refresh then again this alert is shown again to enable the gps

Comment: Don't forget to check 
    if (intent.resolveActivity(packageManager) != null)

Comment: @SamarthKejriwal The same thing happened to me, apparently a colleague found a patch / solution adding: alertDialog.dismiss();
            alertDialog.cancel(); context.startActivity(Intent(action))

Answer (score 11):

```
final Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: `startActivity(Intent(ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS))` - kotlin version