# Google Play Services Location API when GPS is off

Tags: android, gps

What happens when an app uses Google Play Services Location API to fetch user's location and the GPS is disabled?What code is written to make the app ask the user to turn on the GPS?

Also, what code should be written for versions Marshmallow or greater to ask for permission to access location (as versions greater than API 23 ask for permissions on run time of the app).

Also how to handle if the user does not give the permission?

Comment: your questions have already been answered here for hundred times. Why don't you put 2 minutes effort in searching?

Comment: I had searched on google as well as StackOverflow but could not find a helpful answer.. hence asked the question@VladMatvienko

Comment: I don't believe you've searched. I can find answer in ~24 seconds: https://www.google.com.ua/search?q=android+open+gps+enable+settings 
https://www.google.com.ua/search?q=android+request+location+permission

Comment: I said I couldn't find something that i understood. @VladMatvienko

Comment: ok, what is not clear in this answer? https://stackoverflow.com/a/23040461/1568530 
and in this 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/40142454/1568530

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to open GPS settings an android device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23040392/how-to-open-gps-settings-an-android-device)

Comment: Man, im just in the process of learning.. you may be more experienced than me so it may seem easy to you @VladMatvienko

Answer (score 1):

> What happens when an app uses Google Play Services Location API to
>   fetch user's location and the GPS is disabled?What code is written to
>   make the app ask the user to turn on the GPS?

If GPS is disabled, the last known location can be retrieved via Google play services,

1. Create a `GoogleApiClient`

   GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)                        .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
   .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
   .addApi(LocationServices.API).build();

Get the last known location like this,

```
LocationServices.FusedLocationApi
                .getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
```

https://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html

> Also, what code should be written for versions Marshmallow or greater
>   to ask for permission to access location (as versions greater than API
>   23 ask for permissions on run time of the app).
>
> Also how to handle if the user does not give the permission?

From Android Marshmallow, it is necessary to request permission at runtime.Here is the link for it,

https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Comment: @AayushTaneja https://stackoverflow.com/questions/843675/how-do-i-find-out-if-the-gps-of-an-android-device-is-enabled

Comment: No, im not asking for the last location. Im asking how to ask the user to turn on the GPS if it is off?@BatCat