# How do I customize the system settings screen of Android tablet?

Tags: java, android

I am developing an app on Android 11 and I want to open only a specific settings screen from the app.

However, the settings screen in Android 11 is displayed in two columns, so I can select other settings from the menu on the left. Is there any way to hide the left menu (red frame)?

[settings screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kEYhH.jpg)

The code below did not solve the problem.

```
startActivity(new Intent(ACTION_DATE_SETTINGS));
```

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setClassName(
    "com.android.settings",
    "com.android.settings.Settings$DateTimeSettingsActivity"
);
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is no such option for that, security/privacy reasons. you can open some of these screens, [like Wi-Fi settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2318310/how-to-call-wi-fi-settings-screen-from-my-application-using-android) or [GPS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23040392/how-to-open-gps-settings-an-android-device), but not all

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
Has there ever been a request to only allow date and time settings or something like that. Is there any way to disable the menu, such as displaying the menu but not being able to press it, or reducing the width of the menu?

Comment: afaik there is no such `Intent` for that purpose...

Comment: It seems impossible to turn it off. thank you.